# Alternative call-screen

Tags: android, replace, homescreen

I'm developing an alternative call-screen for Android 2.1.

I thought, when I set a call directly in `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony` no android call-screen will appear, but I was wrong.

How can I manage to make the default android call-screen disappear?

Thanks Flo

p.s. I know that `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony` is a private class and I know the risks.